# How to show local notification upon receiving silent push?

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

We are building a react-native IOS application, which uses FCM at the backend and `notifee` at the front end. Everything works, but there are often times when a FCM-data-push is sent but the notification is not shown on IOS if the app is in killed state. Following is the message object that we are sending to the FCM server through `firebase-admin`'s node package.

```
const message = {
    token: fcmToken,
    data: prepared,
    android: {
        priority,
    },
    apns: {
        payload: {
            headers: {
                'apns-priority': 10,
                'apns-push-type': 'background',
            },
            aps: {
                'content-available': 1,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is required to register a task that runs in the background while the app is killed then the registered task handle notification event listens and pushes notification.

Consult this package for  background task - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task

Comment: This works for scenarios where the notification is not time-sensitive. Unfortunately for us, our notifications are required to be shown almost instantly (1-5 seconds delay is acceptable) else there will be cases where the notification will not be valid anymore.

Comment: @LegalRaastaTech are you able to do it. pls help

Comment: @AmbeshTiwari the best we could do is the above code. It sometimes doesn't work. It only works 80% of the time though. And that result is based on our development build. I have yet to see a missed push in a production build.